# How to find number of observation between first observation and first two consecutive negative observations in r

Tags: r, count

I have a large data frame and I need a function to automate this search. 
Basically I want to find how many observations are between the first observation and the first two consecutive negative observations.

Example:

```
x <- c(2, 1, 9, 3, 4, -6, 5, 6, -7, -1)
```

Assuming that this is my data I want to count the number of data points between 2 and -7.

I need to do this in r.

Help is highly appreciated :D !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle` to find the *first two consecutive negative observations* like:

```
i <- rle(!(is.na(x) | x>=0))
j <- i$lengths > 1 & i$values
j <- if(any(j)) min(which(j))-1 else 0
if(j > 0) sum(i$lengths[seq_len(j)])-1 else 0
#[1] 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what it returns                                                           Error in seq_len(min(which(i$lengths > 1 & i$values)) - 1) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In min(which(i$lengths > 1 & i$values)) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: I have add a `max` which should solve the case having two negative numbers in the beginning.

Comment: now it returns Error in seq_len(max(0, min(which(i$lengths > 1 & i$values)) - 1)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In min(which(i$lengths > 1 & i$values)) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: Can you update your example data to meet the conditions where you will use it?

Comment: Sure, here is the data  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 28, 131, 74,164, -207,135, 143, 109, 349, -232.  -671)

Comment: In this case there are no two consecutive negative observations, as `-232. -671` will become `-903` and the function returns -1. Do you mean `-232, -671`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
which.max(cumsum(x < 0) == 2)

[1] 9
```

Comment: `which(cumsum(x < 0) == 2) - 1` if `2` not included

Comment: It returns integer(0)

Comment: Does this take into account the _consecutive_ part? Try it on e.g. `x <- c(2, -1, 9, -3, 4, -6, 5, 6, -7, -1)`